# Bash script unable to send instructions to mysql

Tags: mysql, bash, docker

This is part of a Bash script, and the inside looks like this:

```
createdbcmd="docker exec $1 mysql -v -uroot -e \"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $dbname.* TO $2@$4 IDENTIFIED BY '$3'\"" 
echo $createdbcmd
$createdbcmd
```

the echo looks like this:

```
docker exec mysql_test_no mysql -v -uroot -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress.* TO user@172.17.0.63 IDENTIFIED BY 'changeme'"
```

Running this exact command works just fine. via the bash-script it acts as if i'm just running 'mysql' 
and i get the default help information with no error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
createdbcmd="docker exec $1 mysql -v -uroot -e \"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $dbname.* TO $2@$4 IDENTIFIED BY '$3'\"" 
echo $createdbcmd
eval $createdbcmd
```

Without the `eval`, the quoted expression is not interpreted correctly.

Comment: @user3009620 Then please mark it as accepted! (See that pipe/check shaped icon below the voting arrows next to my post, on the left.)